# ECLIPSE E4 RCP - PreferenceDialog()

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm trying to create a PreferenceDialog() by the way when I set the PreferenceNode like the following example:

```
private PreferenceNode one = new PreferenceNode("one",
            new PrefPageOne());
```

the entry's label on the left-side is not shown at all. It's clickable but there's an empty descriptor.

Any hints?

Comment: Show us the constructor for `PrefPageOne`.

Comment: Ok greg thanks to your reply I checked and noticed that the super contructor wasn't called :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the workaround/solution:

```
public class page extends PreferencePage {
    public page(String title) {
        super(title);
    }
```